# How to get latest data from database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

The error i am getting is "'help' object is not iterable".
How do i fetch the latest record from the db and get it displayed on my destination html page

My views.py is

```
def about_experiment(request,ex_link_name):
    researcher = None
    study = None
    posts = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AboutHelp(request.POST)
        posts = help.objects.filter().order_by('-date')[0]
        #print(posts)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.save()
            researcher = form.cleaned_data['researcher']
            study = form.cleaned_data['study']

    else:
        form = AboutHelp()
    return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'posts': posts})
```

my destination page about_experiment.html is

```
  {% for help in posts %}
  <h4><b>{{ help.study }}</b></h4>
  <p>posted by {{ help.researcher }} on {{help.date}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to import the model? Like `from appName.models import Help` at the top of the views.py file

Comment: Nope its there. I have it

Comment: when you try `help.objects.all()` what happens? Did you install `objects =Manager` in the model?

Comment: All objects get displayed on my destination page when i do Help.objects.all()

Comment: When this is your date in the Model`date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)` you can try to order it in the model like 
`class Meta:  ordering =['-date']` under all the other Model attributes. thats an Idea on how it could work but I have no idea whats wrong with th View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to [voodoo-burger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44876533/2426064) answer:

```
posts = help.objects.filter().order_by('_date')
```

Returns a queryset, which is an iterable. But then you add `[0]`, so you only get one object from the queryset, and hence it will not be iterable.

In your template you therefore you can just use `{{ posts.field_name }}`.

Because you only return one object, `post` is a more logical and descriptive name then `posts` (as mentioned by [voodoo-burger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44876533/2426064))

Answer (score 1):

How did you define the help model? If it is `class Help`, you should change this:

```
 posts = help.objects.filter().order_by('-date')[0]
```

To this:

```
posts = Help.objects.filter().order_by('-date')[0]
```

Comment: It didnt make any diff as my class was class help

Comment: Do you get the error for POST, for GET actions or both?

Comment: its for request method POST

Comment: You can skip the empty filter call, you can call help.objects.order_by directly . Can you check if it makes any difference?

Comment: Yes if i orderby the model attribute such as Help.objects.filter().order_by('-date') it displays the records acc to the date

Comment: I mean, try replacing your code with Help.objects.order_by('-date')

Comment: @FedericoGosman You had the correct answer first. You should have got the check.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ posts }}` in your template is a single object instance of your `help` class, which is not an iterable so you can't use it in a for loop. Instead just use `{{ posts.fieldname }}`.

Also consider changing `posts` to a more logical name. You could use `post` or even `help`.